# Number of Eigenvalues and Scalar of Identity Matrix Relation?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need some help with this problem!

[image]

Let $A \in R^{d×d}$ be a symmetric matrix. Show that $A$ less than or equal to $MI_{d \times d}$ if and only if the eigenvalues of $A$ are at most $M$. Similarly, $mI_{d \times d}$ less than or equal to $A$ if and only if the eigenvalues of $A$ are at least $m$.

Comment: How is the partial ordering defined? What have you tried?

Comment: It looks like you need to go through your notes and find the definition of $\preceq$.   Once you do that, this question should be pretty easy.  Remember for $\lambda_i\in \mathbb{R}$, we know $\sum_{i=1}^d \lambda_i x_i^2$ is non-negative for all $x_i\in\mathbb{R}$ if and only if for all $i$, we have $\lambda_i\geq 0$.